# How to find broken links of a webiste with Selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium

I am very new to Selenium C#. I was searching for ways to find broken links of a website using Selenium C#. I could find a handful of solutions for Java Selenium but I was unable to find using Selenium C#. It would be really helpful if anyone could post a small snippet of code for the same or any link to any document so that I could refer and follow it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

You can try iterate over list of 'a' tags and check for 200 OK in http request:

```
    IList<IWebElement> links = driver.FindElements(By.TagName("a")); 
    foreach (IWebElement link in links)
    {
      var url = link.getAttribute("href");
      IsLinkWorking(url);
    }


    bool IsLinkWorking(string url) {
       HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) HttpWebRequest.Create(url);

       //You can set some parameters in the "request" object...
       request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;

       try {
          HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();
          if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
          {
            Console.WriteLine("\r\nResponse Status Code is OK and 
            StatusDescription is: {0}", response.StatusDescription);
            // Releases the resources of the response.
            response.Close(); 
            return true;
          }
          else
          {
            return false;
          }
       } catch { //TODO: Check for the right exception here
          return false;
       }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
IWebDriver webDriver = new ChromeDriver();
webDriver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.google.co.in/maps/");
HttpWebRequest req = null;
var urls = Driver.FindElements(By.TagName("a"));

foreach (var url in urls)
{
     if (!(url.Text.Contains("Email") || url.Text == ""))
     {
            req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url.GetAttribute("href"));
           try
           {
                var response = (HttpWebResponse)re.GetResponse();
                System.Console.WriteLine($"URL: {url.GetAttribute("href")} status is :{response.StatusCode}");
            }
            catch (WebException e)
            {
                  var errorResponse = (HttpWebResponse)e.Response;
                  System.Console.WriteLine($"URL: {url.GetAttribute("href")} status is :{errorResponse.StatusCode}");
              }
      }
}
```